# Where is the console output on the new CodeSandbox Cloud Web Editor?

Tags: cloud

After hitting this link to upgrade a CodeSandbox to the new [CloudSandbox Web Editor](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/repositories/editors)

[image: ![upgrade link]

I can no longer find the highly useful "Console" and "Problems" windows:

[image: old sandbox console and problems sections]

Where did they go?

EDIT:

It seems that this feature is really gone and the only way to see console logs is now to open the browser inspector. If anybody from CodeSandbox is out there listening: this sucks! I've never *not* wanted to use `console.log` in a CodeSandbox, but now instead of showing that output conveniently right where I want it, in a small window that doesn't take up much space, I have to clutter up my screen layout with the full browser inspector open. This was perfect before the change -- change it back!

Comment: right next to the devbox URL, the third icon button ( preview console ), is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Console.log are printed in your browsers Devtools console tab. You can open it  pressing F12.

Answer (score 1):

In preview tab, if you hover over the third button from the left or second from the right, you'll see the label "preview console". Press on it and on the bottom the devTools window will pop up. Next, press on the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the web viewer to new tab, and then you can inspect the web page.

First, click Dock controls
[image]

and then click this icon at url bar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's under DevTools but it's easy to miss cause it's been renamed `dev:logs`

There's a few ways to open it. From their [DevTools documentation](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/repositories/devtools):

> 1. Clicking on the + sign on the right side of any tabbed panel. This
>    presents a list of available DevTools—and clicking on any DevTool
>    will open it in the current tab.
> 2. Double-clicking anywhere between
>    the tabs and the + button.
> 3. Pressing Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + S.

Comment: `dev:logs` shows me the *server* logs (i.e., the terminal output) -- it does not show me the browser console log (i.e., what I get with `console.log` in the code itself).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The third icon button ( preview console ), is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see it (at least on this link https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/headless-wind-tr1ns)

Comment: @Ooker it's strange. I opened your link and it was exactly there.